# Mutation reductions for parallelStream in Java 8

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-8, java-stream, reduce

**Joshua Bloch** in `<Effective Java> (Third Edition)` mentions that

> The operations performed by Stream’s collect method, which are known as   **mutable reductions**, are not good candidates for parallelism because the overhead of combining collections is costly.

I read the docs on [Mutable reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReduction), but I am still not quite sure **why** reduction is not a good candidate for parallelism. Is it the `synchronization`?

As @Ravindra Ranwala points out (I also saw this on the [Reduction, concurrency, and ordering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReduction) docs):

> It may actually be counterproductive to perform the operation in parallel. This is because the **combining** step (merging one Map into another by key) can be **expensive** for some Map implementations.

If so, then are there other **major factors** we need to care about that might result in low performance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it's **nothing** to do with the `synchronization`. Consider you have a 1 million `Person` objects and need to find out all `people` who live in New York. So a typical stream pipeline would be,

```
people.parallelStream()
    .filter(p -> p.getState().equals("NY"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Consider a parallel execution of this query. Let's say we have 10 threads executing it in parallel. Each thread will accumulate it's own data set into a separate local container. Finally the 10 result containers are merged to form one large container. This **merge** will be costly and is an **additional** step introduced by the parallel execution. Hence parallel execution may not always be faster. Some times sequential execution may be faster than it's parallel counter part.

So always start with a sequential execution. If that makes sense only, you may fall back to it's parallel counterpart at some later point in time.

Comment: Thanks, I read it in the doc. Are there other **influential** factors that we need to think about?

Comment: Thank you, as for **faster** I think I am now not asking about it here. **faster** can be caused by many other factors like **splitting** mechanism, thread **context switching**. What I truly wanna ask is **what are the influential factors the mutation reduction caused to the performance degradation?** Only mutation reduction considered here.

Comment: @Hearen the “the influential factors” are the merging costs. That’s the answer. It’s what Joshua Bloch’s book says, it’s what the documentation says, it’s what this answer says. Why do you insist on assuming that there must be something else?

Comment: @Holger I got it, yes, you are right about it. Sorry for my rudeness and misunderstanding. Thank you so much to clear out the blur in my mind. Thank you, Holger.

Comment: I bet that if you have 1 million people, but only a few of them live in NY, the parallel version will be faster.

Comment: @ciamej Based on what criteria did you draw that conclusion?

Comment: @RavindraRanwala obviously the fewer people live in NY, the lower the cost of the merge, but still you get the benefits of browsing through the data in parallel. Going to the extremes assume that no one lives in NY, then the cost of the merge might be non-zero, but nonetheless very close to zero.